# Weka: how do I score an arff file using a NaiveBayes model?

Tags: naive-bayes, weka

I trained a model with

```
java -Xmx6g -cp /usr/share/java/weka.jar weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes -t train.arff -d foo.nb
```

and I want to score a test file with it.

I tried

```
java -Xmx6g -cp /usr/share/java/weka.jar weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes -T test.arff -l foo.nb -p N
```

which produces no files but writes some text pasts of which can be construed to be scores to stdout (and is unbelievable slow):

```
 inst#     actual  predicted error prediction ()
     1        1:0        1:0       0.549 
     2        1:0        1:0       0.55 
     3        1:0        1:0       0.531 
     4        1:0        1:0       0.515 
     5        2:1        1:0   +   0.552 
     6        1:0        1:0       0.532 
     7        1:0        2:1   +   0.519
```

If I read this correctly, the last column is the score and 3rd is the prediction based on it.  Why does score 0.55 correspond to 0 (instance#2) but a smaller score 0.519 correspond to 1 (instance#7)?

Where is the output documented?

Is there a way to produce the csv score file?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I remember, the output of Naive Bayes is sum-normalized to fake probabilities. Given this and [this piece of documentation](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Making+predictions), the prediction column represent the sum-normalized estimated probability that e.g. instance 1 belongs to class 1 (with label 0) or instance 7 belongs to class 2 (with label 1). Can you please post the output if you use -distribution (see again linked documentation) ?

Answer (score 1):

First I recommend reading about Naive Bayes.

- [a-simple-explanation-of-naive-bayes-classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059594/a-simple-explanation-of-naive-bayes-classification)
- [You tube video of Naive Bayes in NLP class](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DdYSMwEWbd4)

> Why does score 0.55 correspond to 0 (instance#2) but a smaller score 0.519 correspond to 1 (instance#7)?

NaiveBayes decides according to values of two probability predictions not according to if they are near to one. For example class A probability is 0.1 and class B probability 0.12 then class B is the prediction. 
Here score means posterior probability of class given prior probabilities of features.
In the above stack overflow example: Posterior probabilities (scores) was  1/20 and 1/60. Higher one is chosen.

> Where is the output documented?

You may look to class source file. But not everything in weka is well documented. This output is fairly simple therefore I do not think you will find a documentation.

> Is there a way to produce the csv score file?

Use following to get csv prediction output.

```
java_command=java -Xmx6g -cp /usr/share/java/weka.jar 
$java_command weka.classifiers.Evaluation weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes -l irisNaiveBayes.model -T test.arff -classifications weka.classifiers.evaluation.output.prediction.CSV
```

We use [Evaluation](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/Evaluation.html) class instead of using Naive Bayes directly. First argument to Evaluation class is classifier to use, here NaiveBayes. -classification switch allows to output CSV.

Another example with well known iris data set.

```
java_command=java -Xmx6g -cp /usr/share/java/weka.jar 
$java_command weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes -t iris.arff  -d irisNaiveBayes.model

$java_command weka.classifiers.Evaluation weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes -l irisNaiveBayes.model -T iris.arff -classifications weka.classifiers.evaluation.output.prediction.CSV
```

This command gives following output.

```
=== Predictions on test data ===

inst#,actual,predicted,error,prediction
1,1:Iris-setosa,1:Iris-setosa,,1
2,1:Iris-setosa,1:Iris-setosa,,1
3,1:Iris-setosa,1:Iris-setosa,,1
4,1:Iris-setosa,1:Iris-setosa,,1
5,1:Iris-setosa,1:Iris-setosa,,1
6,1:Iris-setosa,1:Iris-setosa,,1
7,1:Iris-setosa,1:Iris-setosa,,1
```

Comment: so, what does the score mean?

Comment: Weka exception: Illegal options: -classifications myout.csv

Comment: Which weka version are you using? 3.6 or 3.7

Comment: @sds I updated my answer for score explanation.

Comment: ubuntu weka 3.6.6-1

Comment: I know the theory. I have been using Bayesian methods for 15 years. What are the numbers in the "prediction" column? Your example is not applicable since I have only one class.

Comment: try weka 3.7 for illegal option.

Comment: yes, 3.7.7 accepts -classifications, but it produces the same inexplicable "prediction" numbers in an invalid CSV format on stdout.